# Junit test fails with ant, succeeds in eclipse: actOnTestResult failure

Tags: eclipse, ant, junit, amazon-web-services

I'm having trouble persuading some new code to play nicely with my JUnit tests when I use ant to run the tests.

I've got some code that interacts with AWS (Amazon Web Services) using the AWS SDK for Java. When my Junit tests come across code that references anything in this SDK, the test fails. The code itself works fine when I step through, it's the pre-existing and otherwise successful Junit tests that are failing.

I've run ant from the command-line using the -v option, and I can see that the jar file for the AWS SDK for Java is included in the classpath. Ant and JUnit are in there as well. The -v option shows that the failure is being reported in actOnTestResult, but that's not where the error itself is occurring.

The full output of the ant -v is:

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 3 2011
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: /home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.6 in: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/jre

Detected OS: Linux

parsing buildfile /home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/build.xml with URI = file:/home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/build.xml

Project base dir set to: /home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy

parsing buildfile jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file

Importing file /home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/lib/one-jar-ant-task.xml from /home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/build.xml

Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper

parsing buildfile /home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/lib/one-jar-ant-task.xml with URI = file:/home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/lib/one-jar-ant-task.xml

Override ignored for property "one-jar.dist.dir"

Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper

Build sequence for target(s) `junit' is [init, compile, junit]

Complete build sequence is [init, compile, junit, input-cmdlineargs, jar, onejar, run-cmdline, input-fileprops, run-hudson, help, clean, usage, input-eclipseargs, run-eclipse, ]


init:

 [echo] Creating build directories...

[mkdir] Skipping /home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/build because it already exists.

[mkdir] Skipping /home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/build/class because it already exists.

[mkdir] Skipping /home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/build/jar because it already exists.

[mkdir] Skipping /home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/dist because it already exists.


compile:

 [echo] Compiling source files...

[javac] /home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/src/AwsCredentials.properties skipped - don't know how to handle it

[javac] com/sportingindex/tradingservices/hadoop/aws/S3DataExtractionDeploy.java omitted as /home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/build/class/com/sportingindex/tradingservices/hadoop/aws/S3DataExtractionDeploy.class is up to date.

[javac] com/sportingindex/tradingservices/test/hadoop/aws/JUnit_S3DataExtractionDeploy.java omitted as /home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/build/class/com/sportingindex/tradingservices/test/hadoop/aws/JUnit_S3DataExtractionDeploy.class is up to date.


junit:

[junit] Implicitly adding /usr/share/ant/lib/junit.jar:/usr/share/java/ant-launcher-1.8.2.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar to CLASSPATH

[junit] Executing '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.6.0_32/jre/bin/java' with arguments:

[junit] '-classpath'

[junit] '/home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/build/class:/home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/lib/aws-java-sdk-1.3.7.jar:/home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar:/home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar:/home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/lib/httpclient-4.1.3.jar:/home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/lib/httpcore-4.2.jar:/home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/lib/junit.jar:/home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/lib/one-jar-ant-task-0.97.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/junit.jar:/usr/share/java/ant-launcher-1.8.2.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar'

[junit] 'org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner'

[junit] 'com.sportingindex.tradingservices.test.hadoop.aws.JUnit_S3DataExtractionDeploy'

[junit] 'filtertrace=true'

[junit] 'haltOnError=false'

[junit] 'haltOnFailure=true'

[junit] 'formatter=org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.SummaryJUnitResultFormatter'

[junit] 'showoutput=false'

[junit] 'outputtoformatters=true'

[junit] 'logfailedtests=true'

[junit] 'logtestlistenerevents=false'

[junit] 'crashfile=/home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/junitvmwatcher8947588636768864827.properties'

[junit] 'propsfile=/home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/junit7746049445603740673.properties'

[junit]

[junit] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are

[junit] not part of the command.

[junit] Running com.sportingindex.tradingservices.test.hadoop.aws.JUnit_S3DataExtractionDeploy

[junit] Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 4, Time elapsed: 0.756 sec


BUILD FAILED

/home/tonyb1/Dev/Workspace/S3DataExtractionDeploy/build.xml:218: Test com.sportingindex.tradingservices.test.hadoop.aws.JUnit_S3DataExtractionDeploy failed

at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.actOnTestResult(JUnitTask.java:1954)

at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:854)

at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.executeOrQueue(JUnitTask.java:1899)

at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask.execute(JUnitTask.java:800)

at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)

at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)

at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)

at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)

at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)

at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)

at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)

at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)

at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)

at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)

at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)

at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)

at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)


Total time: 2 seconds
```

If I run or debug the test through Eclipse, it's fine. It's only when running the test using ant that I get the error.

Comment: QUick question: Do you have `includeantruntime` set to false? What's in  the tests output files? It should list an error there. Maybe a timeout or out of memory?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply David. `includeantruntime` was unset in the `junit` statement; setting it true and I get the same error, setting it false I'll see a "Test ... failed (crashed)" in the ant -v output.

Comment: Not sure where "the tests output files" are - are they created automatically, or do I have to set an option in my build.xml?

Comment: The test XML output files. When you run `<junit>`, you specify where the output goes in either the `<tast>` or `<batchtest>` sub-entity.

Comment: I've got `<batchtest fork="yes" todir="${report.dir}">` as my test sub-entity, $report.dir is set as a property at the top of the build.xml. After I run the test however, that directory is empty.

Comment: Set haltonfailure to false. See if that puts any reports in the `${report.dir}`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - however, setting `haltonfailure` (and `haltonerror`, independently) to false results in no output in $report.dir. Does `batchtest` require any other setting to generate output?

Comment: Do you have `<formatter>` entity? Looking at your output, it looks like it's set to _brief_. Set it to _plain_.

Comment: Bingo, got the output in $report.dir thanks to a `formatter` entity in the `batchtest`. The output is showing the actual exceptions thrown which (I assume) caused the `actOnTestResult` to grumble. Thanks David! I should be able to get to the bottom of it from here.

Comment: Not sure how to +1 your comments David - I only have a Vote ^/v widget by my own original post.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem as you had. I figured out that I need to add one more jar (not only junit.jar):
  hamcrest-core.jar
into classpath.

more: http://junit.org/dependencies.html

Answer (score -1):

You must compare the classpath between ant and eclipse. In my case, i have ant jar in my ant classpath, so i need excude the ant in the ant file if you use the includeruntime=true. And the others , you also should check the test-class and class path in your junit runtime classpath.